Specified non-existing directory symfony 7
I tried to set up the exsiting symfony 7 project using composer install and go the error
"Specified non-existing directory "D:\delivery-on-demand/src/Entity" as Doctrine mapping source."
as shown in the figure below
doctarine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '16'

        profiling_collect_backtrace: '%kernel.debug%'
        use_savepoints: true
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        enable_lazy_ghost_objects: true
        report_fields_where_declared: true
        validate_xml_mapping: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                type: attribute
                is_bundle: false
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App/Entity'
                alias: App
        controller_resolver:
            auto_mapping: true
when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
            dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'
when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
            proxy_dir: '%kernel.build_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies'
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool
    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.app
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.system


The forward slash looks conspicuous; where is that coming from?

not sure. its working on mac but not on my windows. where should i need to change

well, does the directory exist? if the directory was actually deleted, looking for entities in it might fail with the error message posted...

Using composer? You really should use the Symfony app when starting a new project. That way all the directories and what not will be created.

Run composer dump-autoload to regenerate the autoload files. Sometimes the autoloading configuration might be outdated or corrupted.
